# How can I load d3.js with Webpacker in Rails 6?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, d3.js, webpacker

I'm trying to use d3.js in a Rails 6 app with Webpacker and I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined`.

I added d3 using `yarn add d3`.

My `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "d3": "^5.15.0",
    ...
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  }
}
```

`/app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("d3")
...
```

In another JS file I added the following as a way to ensure it's loading properly:

```
...
console.log("test");
const div = d3.selectAll("div");
...
```

I ran `rails s` to restart the Rails server, then reloaded the page.

The log statement is appearing in the console but the d3 line is returning `Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined`.

Comment: did you do `npm install`?

Comment: @shirakia do I need to, given that this is a Rails app?

Comment: In the other JS file, did you import the d3 variable? You’d have to do that in any Webpack-bundled file where you reference the variable.

Comment: @rossta I added `require("d3")` in `/app/javascript/packs/application.js`, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import d3 as a variable to be able to reference it in a Webpack-bundled JS file:

```
import * as d3 from "d3"

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  d3.selectAll("div")
    .append("p")
    .text("Hello, World!")
})
```

Here's a demo: https://github.com/rossta/rails6-webpacker-demo/compare/example/d3

Comment: thank you! Is there a way to import it globally so I don't have to in each file where I need to reference d3? Is that even advisable? There will be dozens of files utilizing d3.

Comment: Update: I added d3 as a plugin to the Webpack configuration in `config/webpack/environment.js`, and that seems to work so I don't have to add the import statement in each file. Is this a good approach?

Comment: That's subjective. I prefer not to because it forces developers to make the dependencies in each module explicit.

Comment: If the solution worked for you, please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: So you recommend adding the `import * as d3 from "d3"` statement to each file in which one needs to use d3?

Comment: That's up to you but it's what I would do in my applications. It's pretty typical for every file in a module-based JS application to begin with one or more import statements.

Comment: Since d3 is itself modular, what you should probably start doing is importing only the part you need for a given file. For example: `import { selectAll } from 'd3'` or `import { selectAll } from 'd3-selection'`

Answer (score 3):

This is what has worked best for me (adding 2 options, easy and efficient):

**1. Add the package via `yarn`**

```
yarn add d3
```

***Easy***

Load the entire d3 library.

**2. config/webpack/environment.js**

Create an alias for the package:

```
const aliasConfig = {
  'd3': 'd3/dist/d3.js'
};

environment.config.set('resolve.alias', aliasConfig);
```

The alias has to point to the main JS file of the package, relative to the `node_modules` folder.

**3. app/javascript/packs/application.js**

Add the import:

```
import "d3"
```

***Efficient***

Load only the functions you are going to use.

**2. config/webpack/environment.js**

No need to add alias using this workflow.

**3. app/javascript/packs/application.js**

import specific functions from d3 submodules, and assign them to a global `window.d3` object:

```
import { select, selectAll } from 'd3-selection'
import { scaleLinear } from 'd3-scale'
import { min, max } from 'd3-array'
...

window.d3 = Object.assign(
  {},
  {
    select,
    selectAll,
    scaleLinear,
    min,
    max
    ...
  }
)
```